# Удаление дубликатов словарей в списке по значению в словаре

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dict

Есть некий список на входе

```
items = [
    {'url': 'ya.ru', 'date': '01.05.2018'},
    {'url': 'ya.ru', 'date': '03.05.2018'},
    {'url': 'google.ru', 'date': '01.05.2018'}
]
```

На выходе необходимо получить

```
items = [
    {'url': 'ya.ru', 'date': '01.05.2018'},
    {'url': 'google.ru', 'date': '01.05.2018'}
]
```

Необходимо удалить дубликаты словарей в списке, данные условные (время может отличаться в миллисекунды), необходимо оставить только уникальные записи по url (время не так принципиально отличия в долях секунд). `set` не работает так как из за этих долей секунд записи в списке не идентичны. Есть ли какой-то элегантный вариант решения?

Comment: не называйте переменные `list`, т.к. это название для встроенной функции `list`, например: `print(list())`, print(list('12345')). После вашего `list = `, показанный в примере код не будет работать. Называйте, например `items`.

Comment: @gil9red спасибо за замечание, в реальности естественно он называется по другому, так как я знаю про зарезервированные слова, приму к сведению на будущее, спасибо за ответ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если значение в `url` является ключевым, тогда можно создать словарь с таким ключом, а его значением будет сам словарь:

```
items = [
    {'url': 'ya.ru', 'date': '01.05.2018'},
    {'url': 'ya.ru', 'date': '03.05.2018'},
    {'url': 'google.ru', 'date': '01.05.2018'}
]

url_by_dict = {i['url']: i for i in items}
new_items = list(url_by_dict.values())

for i in new_items:
    print(i)
```

Консоль:

```
{'url': 'ya.ru', 'date': '03.05.2018'}
{'url': 'google.ru', 'date': '01.05.2018'}
```

Comment: Я всю голову сломал, видимо надо отдыхать, а решение элементарное словарь с ключом по URL который сам перезапишет значение (сам словарь), если повторно встретится в исходном списке. Спасибо !